# Plotting of pandas DataFrame and xaxis as Timestamp produces empty plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime

I have a pandas.DataFrame (df), which consists of some values and a datetime which is a string at first but which I convert to a Timestamp using

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms]'], format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

It seems to work and I can access the new column's element's properties like obj.day and such. So the resulting column contains a Timestamp. When I try to plot this by using either `pyplot.plot(df['datetime'],df['value_name'])` or `df.plot(x='datetime',y='value_name')`,the picture below is the reslut. I tried converting the Timestamps using `obj.to_pydatetime()` but that did not change anything. The dataframe itself is populated by some data coming from csvs. What confuses me, is that with a certain csvs it works but with others not. I am pretty sure that the conversion to Timestamps was successful but I could be wrong. Also my time window should be from 2015-2016 not from 1981-1700. If I try to locate the min and max Timestamp from the DataFrame, I get the right Timestamps in 2015 and 2016 respectively.

[image: Resulting Picture form pyplot.plot]

```py
data = {'Sweep': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
        'Time [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms]': ['11.03.2014 10:13:04.270', '11.03.2014 10:13:06.254', '11.03.2014 10:13:08.254', '11.03.2014 10:13:10.254', '11.03.2014 10:13:12.254'],
        'Frequency [Hz]': [50.0252, 49.9515, 49.9527, 49.949, 49.9512],
        'Voltage [V]': [230.529, 231.842, 231.754, 231.678, 231.719]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms]'], format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")

   Sweep Time [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms]  Frequency [Hz]  Voltage [V]                datetime
0    1.0       11.03.2014 10:13:04.270         50.0252      230.529 2014-03-11 10:13:04.270
1    2.0       11.03.2014 10:13:06.254         49.9515      231.842 2014-03-11 10:13:06.254
2    3.0       11.03.2014 10:13:08.254         49.9527      231.754 2014-03-11 10:13:08.254
3    4.0       11.03.2014 10:13:10.254         49.9490      231.678 2014-03-11 10:13:10.254
4    5.0       11.03.2014 10:13:12.254         49.9512      231.719 2014-03-11 10:13:12.254
```

and `df.info()` gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 33270741 entries, 0 to 9140687
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Sweep                            float64
Time [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms]    object
Frequency [Hz]                   float64
Voltage [V]                      float64
datetime                         datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 1.5+ GB
```

I am trying to plot 'Frequency [Hz]'vs 'datetime'.

Comment: What is `print (df.head())` and `print (df.info)` before ploting ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then set formatting of both axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms]'],
                                   format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")

print (df)

df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)

ax = df['Frequency [Hz]'].plot()

ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
plt.show()
```